Windows error that I can't get to close
I get a pop up error message every time I try to login etc that I can't close.  This is what it says:
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\gameplatformservices.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error.  Try installing the program again using the original installation media or  contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support. Error status OxcOe90002.
Above the message it says: XboxPcAppFT.exe - Bad Image.
I don't have an XBox and I never tried to install an app.  How do I get rid of it (the message and the app)

Can you include a screenshot of the error perhaps? Also, which Operating System and Version are you running? Have you checked for and installed updates? Have you looked into this error in a search engine and read some of the suggestions from others who may have had the problem or a guide for resolving it?

heave you read this
